# How do you find an element when it constantly changes where its nested at?

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I want to scrape my video game stats by going over each win I have, clicking on it, clicking the row with my name on it, and getting all my stats from that game and putting them into a list. here is part of the code I'm having trouble on:

```
           
   nested_lose_lists = []
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    url = "https://destinytracker.com/destiny-2/profile/psn/4611686018440125811/matches?mode=crucible"
    driver.get(url)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    ignored_exceptions=(NoSuchElementException,StaleElementReferenceException)
    crucible_content = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.trn-gamereport-list.trn-gamereport-list--compact")))
    game_reports = crucible_content.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "trn-gamereport-list__group")
    for game_report in game_reports:
        group_entry = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "trn-gamereport-list__group-entries")))
        win_match = group_entry.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"trn-match-row--outcome-win")
        win_match = win_match[0:2]
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", win_match[0])
        lose_match = group_entry.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "trn-match-row--outcome-loss")
        for win_element in win_match:
            #try:    
            win_left = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "trn-match-row__section--left")))
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", win_left) 
            date_time = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "info"))).text
            date_time = date_time.split(",")
            date_time = date_time[0]
            match_roster = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"match-rosters")))
            team_alpha = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.match-roster.alpha")))
            team_bravo = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.match-roster.bravo")))
            bravo_match_roster_entries = team_bravo.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "roster-entries")
            alpha_match_roster_entries = team_alpha.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"roster-entries")
            name2 = "Murtala"
            entry_bravo = bravo_match_roster_entries.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"entry")
            entry_alpha = alpha_match_roster_entries.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"entry")
            nested_win_lists = []
            for entry in entry_bravo:
                details = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "details")))
                name = entry.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "name")#wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "name")))
                

                if name.text == name2:
                    )
                    details = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "details")))
                    details.click()
                    sleep(3)
                    entry_details = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "entry-details")))
                    entry_details = entry.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "entry-details")
                    left_area = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "left-area")))
                    additional_stats = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "additional-stats")))
                    bucket_stats = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "trn-bucket-stats")))
                    additional_stats = left_area.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "additional-stats")
                    bucket_stats = additional_stats.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "trn-bucket-stats")
                    nested_win_list = []
                    for stat in bucket_stats.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "trn-bucket-stat"):
                        value = stat.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"value").text
                        nested_win_list.append(value)
                    nested_win_lists.append(nested_win_list)
                        
                    
                else:
                    
                    skip
                   
                   
            
            wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.close"))).click()
```

Since the location of the name element constantly changes between Bravo and Alpha and is usually nested in the entry element, I wanted to iterate over each entry in both entry_bravo and entry_alpha in order to see if my name is in one of them and click on it and get all the stats from it. here is the picture showing where my name is usually located:
[image]

the issue is that when I run the code and try to print nested_win_lists nothing happens, I know that you can't iterate in a single element so I tried finding the name in the entry text. my goal is to  print something like this:

```
[3,35,9,3.89,13,2.5,12,0.92,0.69,0.81,8M 30S, 0M 4S,8M 2S,9,1,1,0,7,0] #these are all the stats on my games
```

any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you share an example of the sample output?

Comment: when i ran it before a few days ago i got no output at all, now that I run it  I get an error on driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", win_match[0]) saying "list index out of range"

Comment: It seems like the data is available through their api, just use that https://api.tracker.gg/api/v2/destiny-2/standard/matches/psn/4611686018440125811

Comment: im unsure how to use it

Comment: it's just that I come so far using selenium that I would preferably like not to start all over again using API